# How to check Drive and Docs global sharing settings in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Google allows administrators to turn off file sharing outside user's domain. Is it possible to check if this is turned on or off using Google Apps Script?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en

Comment: If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your response. The Access and Permission enums within the DriveApp show the access and permissions of individual files rather than the global sharing settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If you want to share several files, simultaneously, you can do it by giving the permission to a folder. When the folder is given the permission, all files and folders in the folder can be shared, simultaneously. Does this approach your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the situation of sharing file using GAS as follows.

### 1. Retrieve sharing situation of file

[`getSharingAccess()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getsharingaccess) and [`getSharingPermission()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getsharingpermission) are used for this.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("### File ID ###");
var access = file.getSharingAccess();
var permission = file.getSharingPermission();
```

### 2. Modify sharing situation of file

[`setSharing()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype-permissiontype) is used for this.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("### File ID ###");
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
var access = file.getSharingAccess();
var permission = file.getSharingPermission();
```

You can see the detail of `Access` and `Permission` of type at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access.html) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission.html).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.